# Unable to give SNS topic permission on a SQS queue programmatically

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I try to enable a SNS topic to send messages to given SQS queue using the .NET client:

```
var policy = new Policy()
{
    Statements = new List<Statement>() {
        new Statement(Statement.StatementEffect.Allow) {
            Principals = new List<Principal>() { Principal.AllUsers },
            Actions = new List<ActionIdentifier>() { SQSActionIdentifiers.SendMessage },
            Conditions = new List<Condition>
            {
                ConditionFactory.NewCondition(ConditionFactory.ArnComparisonType.ArnEquals, "aws:SourceArn", topicArn)
            }
        }
    }
};

var request = new SetQueueAttributesRequest()
{
    QueueUrl = queueUrl,
    Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { QueueAttributeName.Policy, policy.ToJson()}
    }
};
sqs.SetQueueAttributes(request);
```

This generates a policy that does not work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "<sid>",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<id>:testTopic2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However if I delete this policy and add it manually, it works, and it looks almost identical, with some differences:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:<id>:testQueue2/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "<sid2>",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:<id>:testQueue2",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<id>:testTopic2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The programmatic one:

- lacks `Id`.
- says `"Principal" : "{ AWS: "*"}` rather than `"Principal" : "*"`.

I have tried to set the Id and the principal to a custom one but I only get HTTP 400s.

Which would be the right way of giving a SNS topic permissions to send messages to a SQS queue using the .NET client?

[Full example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86330fbaee4fee6fa5e0bd03bf2c0fa9)

Comment: Isn't it obvious ? You forgot to generate resources in your code. i.e.  ` "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:<id>:testQueue2" `

Comment: :) I replaced the ids with <id>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important part lacking in the JSON generated by your code is

```
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:<id>:testQueue2"
```

Without specifying Resource, IAM can't tell for which resource you are granting access.

Then you can add a Resource object like this:

```
  new Statement(Statement.StatementEffect.Allow) {
     Principals = new List<Principal>() { Principal.AllUsers },
     Resources = new List<Principal>() { new Resource("arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:<id>:testQueue2") }
  ....
```

(I am not a C# pro so syntax may be wrong but you've got the idea.)

Comment: That was fast! :) It makes sense, I will give it a try and come back to you. Thanks!